# Ajax comment system into a do-while loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a comment system that is working fine. But now I wanna make it work into a loop, so it needs is add an id to identify as unique every "comment box", "submit buttom", so on. Due to there are many classes involved I got lost adding the index to the js function ... and actually everything.

This is my code:

```
<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblopiniones_persopoli WHERE id_post = '$id_post' AND intActivo = '1' LIMIT 0,10") or die(mysql_error());
while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
    $name = $affcom['intName'];
    $email = $affcom['email'];
    $comment = $affcom['strComment'];
    $date = $affcom['date'];

    // Get gravatar Image 
    // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
    $default = "mm";
    $size = 35;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5(strtolower(trim($email)))."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;
?>
<div class="cmt-cnt">
    <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" />
    <div class="thecom">
        <h5><?php echo ObtenerNombreFull_Usuario($name); ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"></span>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <?php echo $comment; ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->
<?php } ?>

<div class="new-com-bt" id="<?php echo $m; ?>">
    <span id="">Escribe un comentario ...</span>
</div>
<div class="new-com-cnt">
<a name="coment_box" id="coment_box">
    <input type="hidden" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_IdUser']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="mail-com" name="mail-com" value="<?php echo 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="pic-com" name="pic-com" value="<?php echo ObtenerNombreFoto_Usuario($_SESSION['MM_IdUser']); ?>" />
    <textarea class="the-new-com" placeholder="Ingresa tu comentario"></textarea>
    <div class="bt-add-com">Publicar comentario</div>
    <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancelar</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

My Js code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
    //alert(event.timeStamp);
    $('.new-com-bt').click(function(event){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.new-com-cnt').show();
        $('#coment_box').focus();
    });
    /* when start writing the comment activate the "add" button */
    $('.the-new-com').bind('input propertychange', function() {
       $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:0.6});
       var checklength = $(this).val().length;
       if(checklength){ $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:1}); }
    });

    /* on clic  on the cancel button */
    $('.bt-cancel-com').click(function(){
        $('.the-new-com').val('');
        $('.new-com-cnt').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('.new-com-bt').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });

    // on post comment click 
    $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
        var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
        var theName = $('#name-com');
        var theMail = $('#mail-com');
        var thePic = $('#pic-com');

        if( !theCom.val()){ 
            alert('¡Por favor escribe un comentario!'); 
        }else{ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add-comment.php",
                data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val()+'&pic='+thePic.val(),
                success: function(html){
                    theCom.val('');
                    /*theMail.val('');
                    theName.val('');*/
                    $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                        $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                        $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                    })
                }  
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I'll highly appreciate any help with this lack of knowledge & expertise.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Trata metiendo todo el código que genera el comentario dentro del loop. El problema es que siempre está sobre escribiendo tus variables principales que usas.

Comment: Hola @FernandoUrban el código está ya dentro del loop llamado con un include(). Falta hacer que las clases que correspondan tengan un id único para cada registro del loop y así sean reconocidas individualmente. Creo que las clases que deben tener este id único son "new-com-bt" y "new-com-cnt". Como afectar la función javascript, me queda grande.

Comment: It seems nobody have interest to contribute with this problem.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en javascript no puedes repetir id's. Lo que te recomiendo es que lo manejes por una sola clase y con un each en jquery puedasa recoger un data-id que contenga cada "new-com-bt" y "new-com-cnt".